# Join Stack Overflow in Standing Up for Net Neutrality

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow

Что Stack Overflow от меня хочет?

Join Stack Overflow in [Standing Up for Net Neutrality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/raise-voice-proclaim-need-net-neutrality?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=system-message&utm_campaign=netneutrality)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зачем он мне предлагает что-то написать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это что-то про амеркомнадзор, но некто из америки решил что мы тоже должны это видеть

Answer (score 7):

Внимание, это не официальный поверхностный ответ. Пожалуйста, дополните его или опубликуйте новый!

---

Как я понимаю, это законодательная инициатива в США, которая подразумевает, что интернет провайдеры обязаны предоставлять всем интернет ресурсам равные возможности таким образом, что скорость соединения/пропускная способность каналов связи с каким–либо сервисом зависела только от ограничений скорости на клиенте и производительностью сервера самого сервиса. FCC в США хочет это дело изменить и разрешить операторам интернета самим решать, кому выделить большую пропускную способность, а кому – нет. В результате, например, большие компании имеющие большие бюджеты могут вступить в «коммерческие отношения» с интернет операторами, что даст им бОльшую ширину канала, чем небольшим компаниям, что, в свою очередь, приведет к тому, что новые интернет сайты будут грузиться очень–очень медленно вне зависимости от качества кода на сервере и скорости соединения на клиенте.

Как я понимаю, [вопрос на Мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/) призван спросить у сообщества, что участники думают о сложившейся ситуации, что бы они хотели сделать сами и каких действий ожидают от Stack Overflow, как компании.

Пожалуйста, для большего понимания ситуации прочитайте [публикацию на Мете Мет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297816/), [публикацию в блоге](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/30/raise-voice-proclaim-need-net-neutrality/) и еще один вопрос на [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/).

**Обновление**

Как я понимаю, законодательно этот вопрос затрагивает исключительно США, так как FCC – это комитет в конкретной стране. По факту, интернет – это единая сеть. Так или иначе, чтобы получить код страницы мы должны соединиться с сервером, который находится в NYC, доступ к которому, с большой вероятностью, осуществляется американским интернет оператором (как минимум в финальной стадии).

Comment: Это затрагивает только США или всех?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Предположим канальные операторы на которых сейчас сидит SO зарежут его трафик, но тогда логичным шагом SO будет переход к другим операторам. В итоге текущим операторам не выгодно накладывать такие ограничения, потому что от них начнут уходить клиенты. Хотя при нехватке общей пропускной способности оператор будет перед выбором, потенциально потерять N клиентов, если скорость к ним зарезать, или M клиентов, если будет лагать весь трафик

Comment: @Mike На Экономике про это уже чуть-чуть [рассуждают](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/).

Comment: @Mike проблема не в операторе, к которому подключен SO. Проблема в провайдере, к которому подключены пользователи. Если NN отменят, то такие провайдеры смогут предлагать своим пользователям пакеты вида "тот же безлимит, что был у вас раньше, но с ускоренным доступом к вконтактику Netflix и ютубу! видео загружается мгновенно"!. И пользователи пойдут к ним. Потому что "я вчера был у Васи, у него вконтакте видосики вообще летают". Сделают это они за счет незначительного (на первой стадии) перераспределения канала в сторону вконтактика.

Comment: @Mike а т.к. на рынке ISP в америке олигополия, то крупные ISP смогут  давить на сайты "или заплатите нам, или к вам *ускоренного* доступа не будет". Причем все будут платить. Потому что или ты платишь, или у сайта-конкурента (который заплатил) контент загружается быстрее, и пользователи идут к сайту-конкуренту.

Comment: @PashaPash Ну у нас то по факту это уже давно происходит. Магистральщики ставят у себя кеши гугла и в итоге ютуб идет с кешей и забивает собой, скажем так, на предпоследней миле каналы в итоге другому трафику достается меньше. Яндекс уже несколько лет продвигает прямые стыки на M9 с ISP. И пока вроде проблем особых не наблюдается

Comment: @Mike пока это достигается техническими средствами. Т.е. яндекс вкладывает деньги в инфраструктуру, и делает себя быстрее (но сайты конкурентов при этом не становяться медленее). Отмена NN позволит провайдерам делать то же самое нетехническими средствами - чуть-чуть притормаживать всех, кроме яндекса. Т.е. яндекс будет загружаться значительно быстрее, чем сайты конкурентов (и быстрее, чем у других провайдеров!), а сайты конкурентов - чуть-чуть, незначительно медленее, чем у других провайдеров. Но со временем провайдеры-олигархи эту ситуацию сделают обычной и разница в скорости вырастет.

Comment: @PashaPash, эм.. _"тот же безлимит, что был у вас раньше, но с ускоренным доступом к вконтактику Netflix и ютубу! видео загружается мгновенно"_ - вообще-то сейчас так и есть: http://www.comnews.ru/node/91398

Comment: @Qwertiy ну вот, у вас есть - а в US пока нет, и они не хотят чтобы так было

Comment: @PashaPash, а почему это плохо? Я так понимаю, это на уровне клиентского тарифа регулируется и не является занижением скорости остальных ресурсов?

Comment: @Qwertiy есть два способа ускорить контантик. Первый - построить geoCDN. Второй - дать контактику больший приоритет. Второй способ именно что занижает скорость остальных ресурсов.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вот, предположим, у меня тариф 30 Мбит, для vk на нём делают 100 Мбит. Но я же могу купить тариф со 100 Мбит на всё. Т. е. это ограничение для конкретного клиента, а не то, что ради этого страдают другие сайты. Или я неправильно понимаю?

Comment: @Qwertiy обычно со временем лимиты тарифов растут. Ввод 100 Мбит для контактика означает что не будет 50Мбит для остального интернета.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, эм.. они как бы и так есть, но на другом тарифе...

Comment: @Qwertiy Проблема в том, что в штатах доминируют крупные провайдеры (в РФ скорее всего тоже, а в Беларуси провайдер вообще один). Т.е. тарифы "теперь вконтакте бытрее!" появятся у всех, в нише, в которой сидят 90% пользователей. Т.е. у 90% юзеров станет быстрее вконтакте. Вроде как "бесплатно", или с очень небольшой переплатой. Но если на рынок попытается выйти какой-нибудь facebook - то фейсбуку придется *заплатить провайдерам* за включение себя в список "быстрых" ресурсов.

Comment: @Qwertiy т.е. любой сайт-конкурент "ускоренного" сайта (сайта, который уже заплатил провайдерам) вынужден будет точно так же платить провайдерам. Или он будет тупо медленее, и пользователи от него уйдут. Причем ничего, кроме как заплатить, он сделать не может.

Comment: @PashaPash, области, где важна скорость, можно по пальцам пересчитать. И что-то я не верю, что вдруг сможет появиться конкурент того же ютьюба или контакта, которому было бы нужно доплатить провайдеру за скорость, но на это не будет денег. Только представь, какой там трафик у серверов будет. А какому-нибудь личному блогу это и не надо, наверное.

Comment: @Qwertiy практически везде важна скорость - не столько скорость передачи, сколько скорость отклика. С ютубом и прочим - вопрос не в траффике на стороне сервера. У сайта X видео будет стартовать мгновенно, а у сайта Y - с лагом в 10 секунд. Этого будет достаточно, чтобы на Y никто не пошел. Если SO будет открываться по две секунды, и реагировать на каждый тык по две секунды, а тостер - мгновенно - все уйдут на тостер.

Comment: @PashaPash, какая должна быть разница в скорости, чтобы сделать двухсекундный лаг? Почему сейчас нет такой проблемы?

Comment: @Qwertiy достаточно небольшая. ее можно просто ввести для "плохих" сайтов. Ну и кроме того - принцип NN не дает крупным провайдерам давить VoIP. Почти все провайдеры предоставляют свои сервисы телефонии, и сделать так, чтобы скайп по всей стране чуть-чуть хрипел - для них достаточно просто. Уже сам факт того, что провайдеры вкинули деньги в лоббирование изменений, означает что после внесения изменений они смогут снять с пользователей еще больше денег, прямо или косвенно.

Comment: @PashaPash, да, выглядит логично. А почему, если у нас такое не запрещено, таких проблем нет?

Comment: @Qwertiy есть проблемы, просто вы их не осознаете. т.е. вы переплачиваете за интернет, за связь и прочее. из явных - вот [ростелеком решил сделать аналог скайпа](https://lenta.ru/news/2016/03/04/russianskype/) и тут же решили "внести ясность" - явно уточнить в законе, что байты голосового траффика и http на вкус разные, и что голос нельзя всем подряд передавать. и тем более подключать его к обычным голосовым сетям. и [запретили звонки со скайпа на стационарные телефоны](https://lenta.ru/news/2016/05/20/skype_over/).

Comment: @Qwertiy и вся эта радость - за ваш счет. причем это уже не первый выпад операторов связи (они же провайдеры интернета) в сторону скайпа - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVZJsrymdQM